# Error running Solr

Tags: python, solr, plone

I'm trying to install Apache Solr for Plone, via [collective.solr](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.solr/3.0b5).

I've followed the instructions above, and extended my buildout with:

```
[buildout]
extends =
  buildout.cfg
  https://github.com/Jarn/collective.solr/raw/master/buildout/solr.cfg

[instance]
eggs += collective.solr
```

bin/buildout runs fine, however, when I try `bin/solr-instance fg`

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/solr-instance", line 114, in <module>
    start(False)
  File "bin/solr-instance", line 43, in start
    stdout=logfp, stderr=logfp).pid
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Graceful stop
```

What am I missing / doing wrong?